# avi to mpeg4 command line convertor

Tags: conversion, avi, mpeg4

I am writting program for recording IP cameras videos.
I use Aforge framework and can save video in avi format, but it's size is too big.
I need some command line program to convert videos from avi to mpeg4 format.
Is there any free program and if yes where can I download them and how to use it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can also use ffmpeg. It's a cross platform for recording, converting videos. [You can use it here](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)

Answer (score 3):

As you don't state what OS you are using I would recommend [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) as an excellent free mp4 / h264 encoder.  It's cross platform and has options for Windows, Mac and Linux.

It does have a gui but all the actual work appears to be done in a command line program which on my machine appears to be in the install directory as HandBrakeCLI.exe.  There is a guide as to how to use the command line version at https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/1.1.0/cli/cli-guide.html but it appears that it may possibly be slightly out of date (but probably still largely relevant) as there is a note about it on [this page](http://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/HandBrakeGuide).

It is multithreaded and can easily use all the processors you have available.